# Firefox extension update problem -- SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: json, firefox-addon-webextensions

The company I work for has a Firefox extension that we privately distribute so it isn't in the AMO store. We are able to automatically update our extension using a JSON update manifest. The xpi package includes an update.rdf which has a link to the updated xpi file.

I have been through the process of updating our Firefox extension once before without issue. This time, however, when I try to update the extension through the Add-ons Manager, it responds with the message "No updates found."  This is what is logged in the browser console:

```
1561581031192   addons.update-checker   WARN    onUpdateCheckComplete failed to parse update manifest: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data(resource://gre/modules/addons/AddonUpdateChecker.jsm:288:23) JS Stack trace: onLoad@AddonUpdateChecker.jsm:288:23
UpdateParser/<@AddonUpdateChecker.jsm:239:54

1561581031340   addons.update-checker   WARN    onUpdateCheckComplete failed to parse update manifest: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data(resource://gre/modules/addons/AddonUpdateChecker.jsm:288:23) JS Stack trace: onLoad@AddonUpdateChecker.jsm:288:23
UpdateParser/<@AddonUpdateChecker.jsm:239:54
```

There is no obvious unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of my JSON file, nor hidden characters that I am aware of. The code checks out okay on JSONlint.

The only change I made to the JSON file that worked previously was to update the version number so I don't understand why it wouldn't work this time. I have researched the "JSON.parse: unexpected character" error but didn't find anything pertinent to my situation. Any insights into this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest trying again. Occasionally there are some issues like [Validator fails to read manifest.json](https://github.com/mozilla/addons/issues/888) which are fixed once they are reported. I uploaded an update 2 days ago and didn't have any problems. You can also post your file/s so that it can be checked.

Comment: I've tried three times already over the course of 6 days but no luck. Here is a link to my [manifest.json file](https://pastebin.com/Ua3VNV25) and my [update.rdf file](https://pastebin.com/nA2g1vc9).

Comment: Why are you using XUL rdf? A copy/paste of manifest.json is not enough as encodings change during the copy/paste into 3rd party site. The actual file is needed.

Answer (score 0):

On the Mozilla add-on forum I received a reply that support for the update.rdf file has been deprecated in Firefox 67 1, the “JSON update manifests” file format should now be used instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/Updates. I have passed this issue on to our developer to investigate.